# How to converting string builder to string without escape sequence in the converted string

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005

I am writing some XML data to the stringwriter. I want to pass the values in the stringwriter to the database but when I convert it to a string like

StringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString() it is converting all the " (double quotes) to \"

So when I pass that to database as parameter and when I try to read the data using openXML it's throwing an error.

Is there any work around for this ?

I am using ASP.NET 2.0
SQl server 2005

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly suspect that you're looking at the debugger. That will show the escaped form, but the quotes won't actually be in the string if they shouldn't be.

I suggest you log the string somehow - then you'll see the real data, and my guess is that it won't contain the backslashes - assuming you haven't written any backslashes to the `StringWriter` to start with. How are you writing the data to the `StringWriter`? Is it possible that your problems are further upstream? (If you're writing the XML *manually*, I'd strongly recommend that you use an XML API instead. It's much less error-prone.)

What error are you getting when trying to read the XML back? What does it look like in the database?

I can pretty much guarantee that the problem won't be in `StringWriter` or `StringBuilder` - they don't perform any escaping.

On another note, is there any reason why you're calling `GetStringBuilder().ToString()` instead of just `ToString()`?