# String builder output

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

I currently have a string builder taking the output from an in-memory XSLT transformation. The problem I'm having is when I convert the string builder `.ToString()` to return the contents it is changing all the quotes to `\"`, eg. `<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>`, and this is then causing issue reloading the data into an `XDocument`.

```
StringBuilder OutputXML = new StringBuilder();
XSLTTransformer.Transform(XmlDoc.CreateReader(), writer);
return OutputXML.ToString();
```

I've tried `.Replace("\\\"", "")` however this doesn't work, so how can I prevent/replace these occurances and just keep the string as `"` so the output is `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>`

Comment: Already answered, please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629127/how-to-converting-string-builder-to-string-without-escape-sequence-in-the-conver) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348423/how-to-remove-escape-sequences-from-stream)

Comment: Are you 100% sure that this causing issue?

Comment: Ah yes sorry Mark missed those while prowling google, different search terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you looking at this string?

Because it sounds like you might be looking at it in a debugger, and the debugger represents '"' as '\"'.

So the string itself is fine, and will work fine if presented to a user, saved to file, etc. It just looks escaped in the debugger.

Comment: Yup seems I fell into that one, just run the output to console and it is fine >.<

Comment: Don't worry, you're not the first person, and you won't be the last.

Answer (score 0):

`\"` is just an escape sequence to `"`

In string its `"` only but shows that way in debugger. So no need to worry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a string verbatim before your strings so it will interpret them exactly as they are, just use '@' in front of your strings.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/harishankar2005/verbatim_literals11262005010742am/verbatim_literals.aspx